# Using HTMLUnitDriver on GWT and GXT grids

Tags: gwt, selenium, htmlunit, gxt

We are trying to access a GWT gring and a GXT grid using Selenium HTMLUnitDriver. These grids have an ID assigned and each row in the grid is a  inside .
So, we are accessing the grid element and populate all its rows in to a list as follows:

```
// Find the grid element by its id
WebElement grid = driver.findElement(By.name("gwt-grid")); 

//Get the rows into a list where each row is a table.
List<WebElement> listRows = grid.findElements(By.tagName("table"));

//Pint the number of rows in the list
System.out.println("Total rows: "+listRows.size());
```

The above code works properly on Firefox and IE drivers and gives correct row count (500). But HTMLUnitDriver prints ZERO row count.

I've enebled javascript for HTML Unit Driver as follows:

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

Has anyone faced this issue? Please help me to resolve this issue.